# LINQ to SQL join 3 tables and select multiple columns and also using Sum

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have three tables Student, TimeSheet and TimeRecord.

**Talbe columns:**

- Student : StudentId, FirstName,
  LastName
- TimeSheet: TimeSheetId,StudentId, IsActive
- TimeRecord: TimeRecordId,TimeSheetId, BonusHour(type int), CreationDate

**Table relationship:**

- Student 1:N TimeSheet (FK StudentId)
- TimeSheet 1:N TimeRecord (FK TimeSheetId)

**Student sample data:**

StudentId, FirstName, LastName

- 10 , Macro , John
- 11 , Hiro , Edge
- 12 , Sarah , Lemon

**TimeSheet sample data:**

TimeSheetId, StudentId, IsActive

- 187 ,    10 , True
- 196 ,    11 , True
- 195 ,    12 , True
- 199, 10 , False
- 200 , 12 , False

**TimeRecord sample data:**

TimeRecordId, TimeSheetId, BonusHour, IsValid, CreationDate

- 1 , 187 ,    1 , True , 7/18/2010 10:23:25 PM
- 2 , 196 ,    2 , True , 7/19/2010 2:23:25 PM
- 3 ,  187 ,   1 , False , 8/1/2010 2:5:25 AM
- 4 ,  187 ,   3 , True , 8/9/2010 12:23:13 PM
- 5 ,  196 ,   0 , True , 7/20/2010 6:15:25 PM
- 6 ,  196 ,   2 , True , 9/18/2010 2:23:25 PM
- 7 ,  195 ,   3 , False , 8/18/2010 2:23:25 PM
- 8  ,  199,      4 , False , 7/18/2010 2:23:25 PM

I'd like to get total BonusHour of each student, only Active TimeSheet has Valid BonousHour that count. So, the result will be like something in the following:

For the month of July and so on for the any month

- Hiro Edge has 10hr for July 2010
- Sarah Lem has 8hr for July 2010
- Macro John has 6hr for July 2010

> **Here's what I tried so far:**

```
 Dim query = From ts In db.TimeSheet _ 
                 Join tr In db.TimeRecord On tr.TimeSheetId Equals ts.TimeSheetId _ 
                 Group By ts.StudentId, tr.TimeSheetId Into TotalTime = Sum(BonusHour) 
                 Select StudentId, TimeSheetId, TotalTime
```

I can't get the join of three tables right yet. I can only join two tables so far. I need to join Student table to the query to get student name.

Thanks a lot.

> Update One

```
Dim query = From st In db.Student Select New With { .stName = st.FirstName & " " & st.LastName, _ 
.BonusHours = (From ts In st.TimeSheets Join tr in db.TimeRecord On tr.TimeSheetId Equals ts.TimeSheetId _
                    Where ts.IsActive = True And tr.IsValid = True _
                    Group By key = New With {ts.TimeSheetId, .MonthYear = (tr.CreationDate.Value.Month & "/" & tr.CreationDate.Value.Year)} Into BonusHr = Sum(tr.BonusHour)})}
```

Now, the problem is that how I can get the "MonthYear" out from "BournsHours". Because I want it like this :

- Hiro Edge has 10hr for July 2010
- Sarah Lem has 8hr for July 2010
- Macro John has 6hr for July 2010
- Hiro Edge has 0hr for August 2010
- Sarah Lem has 3hr for August 2010
- Macro John has 2hr for August 2010

and so on for any month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the working query:

```
Dim query = From ts In db.TimeSheets_
            Join tr In db.TimeRecords On tr.TimeSheetId Equals ts.TimeSheetId _
     Where ts.IsActive = True And tr.IsValid = True _
     Group By key = New With {ts.Student, .MonthYear = (tr.TimeOut.Value.Month & "/" & tr.TimeOut.Value.Year)} Into TotalHour = Sum(BonusHour) _
                     Select key.Student.StudentId, key.Student.AssignedId, key.MonthYear, TotalHour
```

Answer (score 2):

*(some C# and alternatives is removed for clarity, see history)*

C# to VB.Net (don't know whether this is correct VB.Net):

```
Dim query = From st In db.StudentNew With { _
 st.FirstName, _
 st.LastName, _
 Key .BonusHours = (From ts In st.TimeSheets _ //Or st.TimeSheet
                    Where ts.IsActive _
                    From tr In ts.TimeRecords _ //Or ts.TimeRecord
                    Where tr.IsValid
                    Select tr.BonusHour).Sum() _
}
```

In cases where you have `unique` on a column you should use `.Single` instead of a `from`. Which `unique`´s do you have on the columns? Is it unique in `TimeSheet`?

If you set up associations with foreign keys LINQ to SQL can make this a lot easier.

**Addition** based on your updated code (I don't think this is actually valid code):

```
Dim query = From st In db.Student
            Let pair = From ts In st.TimeSheets
                       Join tr In db.TimeRecord On tr.TimeSheetId Equals ts.TimeSheetId _
                       Where ts.IsActive = True And tr.IsValid = True _
                       Group By key = New With {
                           tr.CreationTime.Month,year/month - not sure how the syntax will be
                           tr.CreationTime.Year} Into BonusHr = Sum(tr.BonusHour)}
            From part In pair.BonusHr
            Select New With {
                .stName = st.FirstName & " " & st.LastName, _
                .BonusHours = part.BonusHours, _
                .YearMonth = key.Month + " " + key.Year _
            }
```

Comment: Just change a minor flaw (from `TimeRecordId` to `TimeSheetId`)

Comment: TimeSheet has TimeSheetId as PK so, it's unique. StudentId, TimeRecordId are also unique.

Comment: Okay, but can there be multiple timesheets of the same student, is StudentId in TimeSheet unique? Did the code work? Also, see last sentence in my answer.

Comment: Plase see my update in the question. Yes, Tables has relationship. I count only the BonousHour that is valid, and has Active TimeSheet.

Comment: Try my code now - again, I'm not 100% sure its valid VB.net code

Comment: @ lasseespeholt pls see update one in the question. We're almost there.

Comment: Please tell me which code you are currently using so I can clean my answer up a little bit before extending it further :)

Comment: Okay, you can use `Group by key = New With { tr.CreationTime.Month, tr.CreationTime.Year } into ...` this will group it by month

Comment: So, How I can select MonthYear, what I really need from the query are Name, TotalBonusHour, MonthYear. In your updated code, you select only Name and BonusHour as a result. No, MonthYear.

Comment: I tried your code , it's looping. Any idea? It's like for every part in pair select all students. So, first loop select all, second loop select all students ..etc...

Comment: Maybe you should close this question and leave it as it was before you added month/year and then create a new question with the last working code and what you want beyond that. You could get some fresh VB.Net perspectives.

Comment: I give it a few more try. If I can make it I post the answer too. Thanks for the help. :D

Comment: @lasseespeholt see my anwser. I figured it out.

Comment: Good :) Sry, I couldn't help you more than that - but it can be difficult when you don't have test data to test on - and lack of VB.Net knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I know you want VB.NET code, but I don't have much exp in VB.NET so here is C# code.  You can convert it using converters.

Prerequisite: You have set up Entity Framework and associates as necessary.

```
    var q = db.Students
              .Include("TimeSheet")
              .Include("TimeSheet.TimeRecord")
              .ToList();

    q.ForEach(i=>
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}: {2} bonus hours",i.FirstName, i.LastName, i.Sum(ii => ii.BonusHour))
});
```

Edit: Fix typing error